# Can I change the attribute name syntax color for angular 2 attributes, not native HTML

Tags: webstorm

I want to change the syntax highlight for angular attributes (ngFor, ngIf etc..) & (event), [bindings] is possible. or custom directives.

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible, please vote for [WEB-8523](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8523) and linked tickets